# Proper use of Ninject NamedScope

Tags: c#, ninject, named-scope, ninject-extensions

I´m having a hard time trying to understand how Ninject´s NamedScope module should work. In my mind, each (defined)scope should be used to contextualize bindings that are "InNamedScope".

With this toy example:

```
void Main()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NamedScopeModule(), new ContextPreservationModule());

    kernel.Bind<ParentC>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("name", "Name1").DefinesNamedScope("scope1");
    kernel.Bind<Intf>().ToConstant(new MyC() { ID = 1} ).InNamedScope("scope1");

    kernel.Bind<ParentC>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("name", "Name2").DefinesNamedScope("scope2");
    kernel.Bind<Intf>().ToConstant(new MyC() { ID = 2 }).InNamedScope("scope2");

    kernel.GetAll<ParentC>().Dump();
}


public class Intf
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}


public class MyC : Intf
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class ParentC
{
    public ParentC(Intf[] c, string name)
    {
        this.C = c;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Intf[] C { get; set; }
}
```

for me, should yield something like this:

[image]

But instead, I get an exeception:

> UnknownScopeException: Error activating UserQuery+Intf
>   The scope scope2 is not known in the current context.

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ninject, scope is related to lifetime of objects. I see named scope more as a way of injecting the same instance into different classes, like this:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent(Child child, GrandChild grandChild) {}
}
public class Child {
    public Child(GrandChild grandchild) {}
}
public class GrandChild {}

kernel.Bind<Parent>().ToSelf().DefinesNamedScope("scope");
kernel.Bind<GrandChild>().ToSelf().InNamedScope("scope");

kernel.Get<Parent>();
```

The `grandChild` injected into `Parent` is the same instance as is injected into `Child`.

Comment: It makes sense, I guess I misunderstood the purpose of of ninject scope. Is there any extension that does what I am trying to accomplish ? Or should I use `Named(..)` and `WhenAnyAncestorNamed(..)`

Comment: Yes, `Named(...)`and `WhenAnyAncestorNamed(...)` would probably work for that. Your toy example reminds me of another SO question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864334/ninject-binding-a-tree-of-data and the recommendation there is to use Ninject to bind graphs of components, not data centric objects.

Comment: Agree.. this was only to simplify the example, my real issue was trying to use different bindings (to different classes) using NamedScope. Thanks for helping.